# Regex expression to split string into items

Tags: .net, regex, split

I've got text in a form of

```
[1/12/2008 2:32:11 p.m. - name]
line 1
[1/12/2008 2:36:00 p.m. - name] - PRIVATE
line 2 [some text] sd
[1/12/2008 2:36:00 p.m. - name]
line 3
```

which i want to split into items so i have access to time, name and text of each item,

```
e.g.:
(item 1)
  1: 1/12/2008 2:32:11 p.m.
  2: name
  3: line 1
(item 2)
  1: 1/12/2008 2:36:00 p.m.
  2: name
  3:  - PRIVATE
    line 2 [some text] sd
(item 3)
  1: 1/12/2008 2:36:00 p.m.
  2: name
  3: line 3
```

I was trying to come up with a single regex pattern to achieve this, but no luck:

```
\[([0-9\/ \:\.apm]+?) - ([a-z_\-0-9]+?)\](.*?\r\n.+?)(?:\[[0-9\/ \:\.apm]+? - [a-z_\-0-9]+?\])
```

This pattern above only returns the first item.

```
\[([0-9\/ \:\.apm]+?) - ([a-z_\-0-9]+?)\](.*?\r\n.+?)(?!\[[0-9\/ \:\.apm]+? - [a-z_\-0-9]+?\])
```

The pattern above returns all items, but only first character of the text (group 3)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this gets you what you want.

```
\[([0-9\/ \:\.apm]+?) - ([a-z_\-0-9]+?)\](.*?\r\n.+.*?)
```

I tested it out on [my RegEx tester](http://iowacomputergurus.com/free-products/regular-expression-tester.aspx) and it appears to get the proper format.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your example and i hasn't worked initially. Then it turned out that "single line" regex option was causing it not to work. Removing "single line" option solved it.

Comment: @CheGueVerra - No problem!  I'm hoping to release a new version also in the next few days, as there is a "bug" with the way that it renders HTML/XML matches.